# Scribblenauts Remix (iPad) "How do you undo the effects of a "Time Machine?"

Tags: scribblenauts-remix

I suggested to my daughter that she create a Time Machine in Scribblenauts Remix.  I had not idea what it did.  Apparently she lost all her words and items and she is now very angry with her dad (me, ugggh).  Can anyone tell me how to UNDO the effects of a Time Machine so that she regains all the items that she created before we created it.
Much thanks!!!! R

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but it is said that the Time Machine reset the playground. I don't think that you can undo this.. and good luck with your daughter ! :)